# Cambiar src de ImageView por el nombre de una imagen Android studio

Tags: android, imagen, kotlin, android-imageview

¿Como puedo cambiar la imagen de un ImageView dinamicamente mediante el nombre de la imagen?

Supongamos que tengo un botón blue_yellow, uno black_white y uno default; Al mismo tiempo tengo una imagen con diferentes fondos en la carpeta drawable:

- manzana_blue_yellow
- manzana_black_white
- manzana_default

Tras presionar un botón necesito cargar la imagen la respectiva. Es decir, si presiono el boton black_white, el imageview deberá mostrar la imagen llamada **manzana_black_white** si presiono el botón default mostrará **manzana_default**.

Esto en realidad es para varias imágenes que tengo en un ArrayList de ImageView,
todas las imágenes tienen su respectivo prefijo del color que se repite.

La lógica que tengo en mente seria obtener el nombre de la imagen (Ej: manzana_black_white) y hasta el primer guion bajo es el nombre de la imagen, luego continua el color que está puesto actualmente; una vez obtenido el nombre de la imagen mediante manipulación de string **manzana_** agregar el string del color que necesito **_blue_yellow** consiguiendo así el nombre de la imagen que necesito **manzana_blue_yellow** y con ello buscar el recurso con ese nombre para poder setearlo en el ImageView Respectivo.

Mi array con todos los imageview llega al constructor de la clase

```
val imgs: ArrayList<ImageView>?
```

La función que quiero utilizar para cambiar las imagenes

```
fun changeImage(color:String){
    when(color){
        "blue_yellow" -> {
            if (imgs != null) {
                for (img in imgs){
                    /*Acá deberia cambiar la imagen actual por la con prefijo blue_yellow*/
                }
            }
        }

        "black_white" -> {
            if (imgs != null) {
                for (img in imgs){
                    /*Acá deberia cambiar la imagen actual por la con prefijo black_white*/
                }
            }
        }

        "white_black" -> {
            if (imgs != null) {
                for (img in imgs){
                    /*Acá deberia cambiar la imagen actual por la con prefijo white_black*/
                }
            }
        }

        "default" -> {
            if (imgs != null) {
                for (img in imgs){
                    /*Acá deberia cambiar la imagen actual por la con prefijo default*/
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

La idea es que al hacer click en el botón yo pueda llamar a esta función y pasar el prefijo, con ello cambiar todas las imagenes respectivas dentro del ImageView

Comment: eso es kotlin? lo digo por meter la etiqueta apropiada

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`setImageResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) de la siguiente manera:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/manzana_" + color, null, null);
img.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Eso es la forma "genérica" de cambiar a una imagen, no se adapta a la problemática.

Comment: Se me pasó eso, ahí actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, tenia en consideración eso. Ahora, para obtener el nombre de la imagen actual voy seteando sus tag, o conoces alguna manera más simple de obtener el nombre del recurso ?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "voy seteando sus tag"?

Comment: Para poder realizar el cambio de imagen necesito obtener el nombre actual del recurso, la propiedad drawable me devuelve el id android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@3f9dc5d; Con setear los tags me refiero a ir utilizando la propiedad tag de imageview para poner el nombre de la imagen ahí y así reconocer de manera "simple" el nombre, ya que desconozco si hay una función o propiedad que traiga el nombre y no la id del recurso

Comment: Que yo sepa no hay otra forma de obtener el nombre actual del recurso.

Comment: Gracias! entonces lo haré así y publicaré el código para ver si luego le ayuda a alguien más :)

Answer (score 1):

La función que cambiará la imagen

```
fun changeImage(color:String){
    if (imgs != null) {
        for (img in imgs){
            if (img.tag.toString().isNotEmpty()){
                val onlyName = img.tag.toString().split("_")
                val id = ctx.resources.getIdentifier("${onlyName[0]}_$color", "drawable", ctx.packageName)
                img.setImageResource(id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**imgs** En la funcion es un ArrayList que lo hago llegar desde el constructor de la clase, pero perfectamente se lo podrían pasar como parámetro a la función.

El ImageView (Es vital tener el tag con el nombre de la imagen ya que en base a eso luego vamos a buscar las otras)

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_imc"
     style="@style/img_result"
     android:tag="imc_default"
     android:src="@drawable/imc_default"/>
```